# java streaming parent and children into one list

Tags: java, java-stream

**TL;DR:** turn a list of parents with children into a list of persons using java streaming api.

Let's assume the following classes:

```
public abstract class Person {
    private String name;
}

public class Parent extends Person {
   List<Children> children;
}

public class Child extends Person {
    int age;
}
```

The following code would give me a list of all children

```
List<Child> allChildren = parents.stream()
    .flatMap(p -> p.getChildren().stream())
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I like to get a list of all persons so including parents. Is this at all possible with java 8 streaming?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can add the parents to the stream [using `Stream::concat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#concat-java.util.stream.Stream-java.util.stream.Stream-):

```
List<Person> persons = parents.stream()
    .flatMap(p -> Stream.concat(Stream.of(p), p.getChildren().stream()))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```